# Removing Overlapping by adding a value to a date column caused an overflow

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My question is related to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60651856/avoid-overlapping-in-by-adding-a-day-in-bi-startdate) . When I try to execute this query :

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             lag(enddate) over (partition by employee order by startdate) as prev_enddate
      from MyTable t
     ) 
update toupdate
    set startdate = dateadd(day, 1, prev_enddate)
    where startdate <> dateadd(day, 1, prev_enddate);
```

I am having this error message :

> Adding a value to a 'date' column caused an overflow.

Knowing that :

```
SELECT MIN(BI_StartDate),MIN(BI_EndDate),MAX(BI_StartDate),MAX(BI_EndDate)
FROM MyTable
```

The ouput :

```
MinBIStart  MinBIEnd    MAXBIStart  MAX BIEnd   
1900-12-31  2017-06-27  2020-03-27  9999-12-31
```

Comment: The problem is most certainly caused by 9999-12-31... you should handle this with some `CASE`, such as `CASE WHEN prev_enddate < '9999-12-31' dateadd... ELSE '9999-12-31'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the problem is coming from the `where` clause:

```
update toupdate
    set startdate = dateadd(day, 1, prev_enddate)
    where (case when prev_enddate < '9999-12-31'
                then 'false'
                when startdate <> dateadd(day, 1, prev_enddate)
                then 'true'
           end) = 'true'
```

Or, you can replace the logic with:

```
where dateadd(day, -1, startdate) < prev_enddate
```